# Check if String "Date" is longer than 7 days

Tags: java, string, date, time

I receive an amount of dates in strings like this:

```
"2018-01-10T14:10:03.000+0200"

"2018-01-03T12:17:35.000+0200"
```

Since that is too complicated for me to work with, I cut them down with the substring method and I save them in a string in this format:

```
String date = "2018-01-10";
```

**How can I know if a string that includes a date in this format is longer than 7 days from Now?**

My solution was to save every part of the date as integers (int year, int month, int day) or something similar, and use if clauses to find out in the end if the date is within the 7 day limit or not, but this seems to be way too complicated and I'm pretty sure someone has found an easier solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: And why you try to manipulate those dates as String instead of using the proper date types? Have you looked at [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When manipulating dates, you are better off using appropriate date/time objects than playing with strings. The format looks complex but it is not difficult to parse with built-in classes.

In your case, it could be a reasonably short:

```
String date1 = "2018-01-03T12:17:35.000+0200";
String date2 = "2018-01-10T14:10:03.000+0200";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSx");
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                    OffsetDateTime.parse(date1, fmt),
                    OffsetDateTime.parse(date2, fmt));
```

Comment: You don’t need an explicit formatter. As far as I can tell, the strings conform with ISO 8601, the format that `OffsetDateTime` and the other modern date-time classes read as their default.

Comment: If the OP wishes to consider only the dates, convert to `LocalDate` before calculating the difference.

Comment: @ assylias I'd still rather have everything before T because I don't really need the rest. However, your solution throws this: `DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-01-12' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2018-01-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: @OleV.V. I tried using your suggestion, and I also converted LocalDate to String and it throws this: `DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-01-09' could not be parsed at index 10`

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-03T12:17:35.000+0200").toLocalDate()`?

Comment: @OleV.V. nope, it throws the same but at index 23 now. It's totally fine, I used gohil90's solution which works perfectly fine for me even though you are discouraging the use of it :P

Comment: Ah, the bug in Java 8. It works in Java 9. One good workaround is adding the `DateTimeFormatter` from assylias’ answer. Sorry I wasn’t aware.

Comment: @JohnDaniel That other Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone, implicitly using the JVM’s current default time zone. That default may vary by Machine and may even vary *during* runtime. So your results may vary. Avoid those troublesome old date-classes like the Plague.

Comment: The Java 8 bug mentioned is in parsing the offset `+0200` lacking a colon between the hours and minutes portions. Fixed in Java 9. Specifying the formatting pattern is a workaround.

Comment: Okay, I managed to make this solution work, and indeed it is buggy as hell. Choosing this as the correct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, convert date string into Date format like -

```
String date = "2018-01-10";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date yourDate = format.parse(date);
```

Then, compare it with current date -

```
Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).getTime();
int diffInDays = (int) ((todayDate.getTime() - yourDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Check if `diffInDays` is more than 7 or not. You have your solution.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Only tried to provide Java7 solution :) But you do have a point. @OleV.V.

Comment: In my very honest opinion the Java 7 solution is to get the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the modern Java date and time API (first described in JSR-310, hence the name) and then use it for the task. Works in Java 6 and later.

Comment: This Answer is inappropriately using a date plus time-of-day type to represent a date-only value. Instead, use `LocalDate` for a date-only value. For Java 6 & 7 use the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For earlier Android, use the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Comment: Another problem: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone.